# How do I create a function in MySQL that is not attached to a schema/database?

Tags: mysql, function

I am trying to figure out how I can create a function in MySQL that would be accessible from any schema/database.

I tried:

```
DELIMITER $$
USE ``$$
CREATE FUNCTION . . .
```

But I get an error message: No database selected

Comment: I doubt this is possible; but hey, why not tie it to the `test` db? Or some other globally accessible db.

Comment: MySQL doesn't support schemas. It only supports databases ("catalogs" in standard SQL terms).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name …which are called "schema" in the MySQL documentation.

Comment: @feeela: interesting, they are not called "schema" in the JDBC driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @Jack [said in the comment below my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805637/how-do-i-create-a-function-in-mysql-that-is-not-attached-to-a-schema-database#comment18991871_13805637), it would appear as if this is not possible. For now I created a functions schema/database and added my function to that.